# cmake parse error :Invalid escape sequence \o

Tags: cmake

I have a lot of similar error alert info like this type:

```
 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
    Syntax error in cmake code at

      C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

    when parsing string

      Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts

    Invalid escape sequence \o
```

The file `C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake` is 
like is:

```
#add data
 macro(add_files_macro FPATH FGROUP)
     file(GLOB GDAL_AHHEADERS ${FPATH}/*.h  ${FPATH}/*.hpp)
     set(GDAL_HHEADERS ${GDAL_HHEADERS} ${GDAL_AHHEADERS})
     source_group("Header Files\\${FGROUP}" FILES ${GDAL_AHHEADERS})
     file(GLOB GDAL_ACSOURCES ${FPATH}/*.cpp ${FPATH}/*.cc ${FPATH}/*.c)
     set(GDAL_CSOURCES ${GDAL_CSOURCES} ${GDAL_ACSOURCES})
     source_group("Source Files\\${FGROUP}" FILES ${GDAL_ACSOURCES})
 endmacro()
```

Below is the CMake error info:

```
gdal version=[1.9.0]
 GDAL lib name ... wxgisgdal19
 c++ compiler ... cl
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:92 (option):
   option called with incorrect number of arguments: BUILD_RELEASE_DEBUG_DIRS
   Set OFF to build each co# uninstall target

   configure_file(

        C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in 
        C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/build/cmake_uninstall.cmake 
       IMMEDIATE @ONLY)nfiguration to a separate directory ON 


 Found GEOS: C:/geos-3.2.3/lib/geosd.lib
 Found Proj: C:/PROJ/lib/proj.lib
 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:121 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:121 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\generic

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:122 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\generic

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:122 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\mem

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:125 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\mem

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:125 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\vrt

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:130 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\vrt

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:130 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\csv

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:135 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\csv

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:135 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\dxf

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:140 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\dxf

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:140 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\shp

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:145 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\shp

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:145 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 Found PostgreSQL: C:/pgsql/lib
 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\pg

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:158 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\pg

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:158 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\gml

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:163 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\gml

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:163 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\mitab

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:168 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\mitab

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:168 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 Found LIBKML: C:\Users\Public\libkml-read-only\msvc\Debug
 Found LIBKML Headers: C:/Users/Public/libkml-read-only/src
 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\libkml

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:184 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\libkml

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:184 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\kml

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:187 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\kml

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:187 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\geojson

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:193 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\geojson

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:193 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:5 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:5

   when parsing string

     Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\geojson\jsonc

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:195 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:8 (source_group):
   Syntax error in cmake code at

     C:/yumen/wxgisgdal-read-only/cmake/common.cmake:8

   when parsing string

     Source Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts\geojson\jsonc

   Invalid escape sequence \o

   Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/ogr.cmake:195 (add_files_macro)
   CMakeLists.txt:135 (include)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 Found JPEG: C:/GnuWin32/lib/jpeg.lib 
 Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

A guy told me that I should add something like this:

In `Header Files\\ogr\ogrsf_frmts` need to add terminator `'\'` like this:

```
"Header Files\\ogr\\ogrsf_frmts"
```

but as I paste the `common.cmake` file content line 5:

```
source_group("Header Files\\${FGROUP}" FILES ${GDAL_AHHEADERS})
```

the string after Header Files is replaced by `FGROUP` macro, may generated automatically by CMake, so I can not edit them.

Answer (score 7):

The error is happening because the contents of the variable `${FGROUP}` contain paths with Windows-style separators.  These are treated by CMake as escape characters.

You should change your [`macro`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3amacro) to a [`function`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afunction) to avoid this.  From the docs for `macro`:

> Note that the parameters to a macro and values such as `ARGN` are not variables in the usual CMake sense. They are string replacements much like the c preprocessor would do with a macro. If you want true CMake variables you should look at the `function` command.

Comment: Would using a function actually help? The second argument to `add_files_macro` apparently contains an unescaped backslash; CMake will interpret this as an escape sequence either way.

Comment: No - the error message shows that the macro is being called correctly because the line quoted is inside the macro body (at line 5 in the `source_group` call).  If the string contained an unescaped backslash, the error would detail the point at which the macro is called, not inside the macro itself.  Changing to a function will fix this since it treats its arguments differently.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I was not aware of this particular distinction between functions and macros. Well, the day you stop learning is the day you die.

Comment: you mean I change the common.cmake file content to :#add data
function(add_files_macro FPATH FGROUP)
    file(GLOB GDAL_AHHEADERS ${FPATH}/*.h  ${FPATH}/*.hpp)
    set(GDAL_HHEADERS ${GDAL_HHEADERS} ${GDAL_AHHEADERS})
    source_group("Header Files\\${FGROUP}" FILES ${GDAL_AHHEADERS})
    file(GLOB GDAL_ACSOURCES ${FPATH}/*.cpp ${FPATH}/*.cc ${FPATH}/*.c)
    set(GDAL_CSOURCES ${GDAL_CSOURCES} ${GDAL_ACSOURCES})
    source_group("Source Files\\${FGROUP}" FILES ${GDAL_ACSOURCES})
endfunction()