# cmake generate error on windows as it uses \ as escape seq

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I have something such as this in my cmake:

```
set(MyLib_SRC $ENV{MyLib_DIR}/MyLib.cpp)
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${MyLib_SRC})
```

but when I ran the cmake, I am getting this error:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:97 (add_library):
Syntax error in cmake code when parsing string

D:\New\Development\Lib/myLib.cpp

Invalid escape sequence \N

Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
"cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I read this OS answer [cmake parse error :Invalid escape sequence \o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112279/cmake-parse-error-invalid-escape-sequence-o) but How can I chang the macro (which macro!) to a function?

The value of env variable is

```
MyLib_DIR=D:\New\Development\Lib
```

Comment: @Angew: updated question with value of env variable, other variables are calculated based on this env variable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `$ENV{MyLib_DIR}` expands the environment variable verbatim, including the backslashes used as path separators. These can then get re-interpreted as escape sequences.

What you want to do is convert the path to CMake's internal format before handling it in CMake code:

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{MyLib_DIR} MyLib_DIR)

set(MyLib_SRC ${MyLib_DIR}/MyLib.cpp)
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${MyLib_SRC})
```

Answer (score 6):

As indicated in Angew's answer, the backslashes in your environment variable are being interpreted as escape sequences. As of CMake 3.20, there are a host of path manipulation tools provided by the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html) command. Using the [`SET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html#modification) option, this command will convert the input into a CMake path with forward-slashes (`/`):

```
cmake_path(SET MyLib_SRC $ENV{MyLib_DIR}/MyLib.cpp)
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${MyLib_SRC})
```

The `MyLib_SRC` variable will now contain forward-slashes:

```
D:/New/Development/Lib/MyLib.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose cmake always expects UNIX-style path.
So, what I do is

```
set(MayLib_PATH $ENV{MyLib_DIR})
string(REPLACE "\\" "/" MayLib_PATH "${MayLib_PATH}")
```