# CMake: how to normalize paths?

Tags: cmake

Is there a robust way to normalize paths in CMake?

Example:

```
# Let's assume that an environment variable MY_ROOT_DIR is set
# that points to some directory.
set(MYFILE "$ENV{MY_ROOT_DIR}/somefile.txt")
message(${MYFILE})
# This will result for example in 
# Win:         C:\path\to\my\root\dir/somefile.txt
# Unix based:  /path/to/my/root/dir/somefile.txt
```

In this example, it would be required to normalize `MY_ROOT_DIR` (that is to replace backslashes with slashes) prior to using it as path component. How would you do this in CMake?

CMake (or the tools further down the toolchain) may handle paths with mixed separators (`/` or `\`), or may not. CMake uses `/` as the standard separator. A typical warning generated by CMake for paths with the wrong path separator `\` may look similar to this:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake_install.cmake:5 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/path/to/my/root/build/cmake_install.cmake:5

  when parsing string

    C:\path\to\my\root/somefile.txt

  Invalid escape sequence \p

  Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
```

Thanks for any hints on this!

Comment: I agree. The answer certainly is :)

Comment: ...although I was not able to find that other post when looking for a solution of my problem.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`file(TO_CMAKE_PATH)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command for this.

> The `TO_CMAKE_PATH` mode converts a native `<path>` into a cmake-style path with forward-slashes (`/`). The input can be a single path or a system search path like `$ENV{PATH}`. A search path will be converted to a cmake-style list separated by `;` characters.

Here is an example:

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "$ENV{MY_DIR_VAR}" ENV_MY_DIR_VAR)
```

Comment: As of CMake 3.20, you can now also use the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html) command to convert paths to CMake paths with forward slashes. See my response in the duplication question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304591/3987854).