# File path from CMake as string in C++

Tags: c++, string, cmake

In CMake, I have the following snippet:

```
set(FILE_PATH "" CACHE STRING "Full path of the file")
add_definitions(-DFILE_PATH="${DATA_SET_PATH}")
```

In C++ code, I have this snippet:

```
std::string my_file_path = std::string(FILE_PATH);
```

Which works well except for this case:
If some one on MS Windows and copy the file path to the CMake GUI as following:

```
C:\nnn.txt
__^____
```

Instead of:

```
C:/nnn.txt
__^____
```

or:

```
C:\\nnn.txt
__^^___
```

It is going to cause a problem because of the escape character.

What options do I have to solve this problem other than telling the developer to pay attention for the "\ thing"?

I thought of replacing all singles `\` with `/` but I realized that there is nothing called single `\` and you can not search for single `\` if it was injected in the string as single `\` instead of double `\\`.

BTW, any way to fix this problem is much appreciated even if it was on CMake level not C++ code level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some remarks/solutions on the CMake side of it

1. You should use `FILEPATH` instead of `STRING` cache type

   ```py
   set(FILE_PATH "" CACHE FILEPATH "Full path of the file")
   ```

   From the [`set()` command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry):

   > `FILEPATH` : Path to a file on disk. [cmake-gui(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html#manual:cmake-gui(1)) offers a file dialog.

   This does add the little `...` button at the end of your cached entry:

   [image]
2. You should probably set policy [`CMP0005`: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped automatically](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0005.html) to `NEW`

   ```py
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0005 NEW)
   ```

   That would handle the proper escaping if the user does manually paste a file path including backslashes.
3. You could use the [`file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command to normalize the path like:

   ```py
   set(FILE_PATH "" CACHE FILEPATH "Full path of the file")
   file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${FILE_PATH}" FILE_PATH_NORMALIZED)
   add_definitions(-DFILE_PATH="${FILE_PATH_NORMALIZED}")
   ```

**References**

- [CMake: how to normalize paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910256/cmake-how-to-normalize-paths)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `config.h.in` approach and `configure_file()` CMake call?

Additionally, there is raw string literals in C++ 11 and later, so `R"(c:\n.txt)"` is actually the same as `"c:\\n.txt"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about the first method and it seems that it could be a solution. However, about the second approach, I thought about it but I could not come up with a way to encapsulate a predefined macro with R"()".. How is that possible?

Comment: You could add R"()" within Cmake script. However, I'd like to recommend using configure_file instead of defines. It looks easy and clear.