# Cmake fails in compiling Caffe with lmdb.h

Tags: c++, cmake, caffe, lmdb

Windows 10 Visual Studio 14

I am trying to build a c++ code based on [this github page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rweq0.png). However, when I try to generate lib files in Cmake I get this error:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with lmdb.h file. Should I build lmdb from scratch?

There are 2 error messages:

1. > CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Dependencies.cmake:46 (find_package):
   >   Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses _ROOT
   >   variables.   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details. 
   >   Use the cmake_policy   command to set the policy and suppress this
   >   warning.
   >
   > Environment variable HDF5_ROOT is set to:
   >
   > ```
   > C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.3
   > ```
   >
   > For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable. Call Stack (most
   >   recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:49 (include) This warning is for
   >   project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
2. > CMake Error at cmake/Utils.cmake:105 (if):   Syntax error in cmake
   >   code at
   >
   > ```
   > C:/Project/RCNN/Faster RCNN/caffe-faster-rcnn-dev/cmake/Utils.cmake:105
   > ```
   >
   > when parsing string
   >
   > ```
   > C:\Project\RCNN\Faster RCNN\Packages\lmdb-mdb.master\libraries\liblmdb/lmdb.h
   > ```
   >
   > Invalid escape sequence \P Call Stack (most recent call first):
   >   cmake/Modules/FindLMDB.cmake:25 (caffe_parse_header)
   >   cmake/Dependencies.cmake:52 (find_package)   CMakeLists.txt:49
   >   (include)
   >
   > [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rweq0.png): https://github.com/D-X-Y/caffe-faster-rcnn/tree/dev   [2]:
   >   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc30J.png

Also the paths for GLOG, GFLAGS, and PROTOBUF are not found.

Comment: Please copy-paste errors as text. The text in the image is hard to read.

Comment: The problem is is caused by an unescaped windows path in one  of the variables. It would be interesting to see the code for FindLMDB.cmake. I believe the fix may need to be there.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I added the text of errors.

Comment: @drescherjm Are you sure this has nothing to do with GLOG, GFLAGS,... ?

Comment: ***Invalid escape sequence \P Call Stack (most recent call first):*** is pretty clear since your path is C:\Project ... the problem is CMake prefers paths to use / instead of \

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070810/cmake-generate-error-on-windows-as-it-uses-as-escape-seq

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. The backslashes were the problem. But what about the first error (HDF5)? I have defined HDF5_ROOT as an environment variable.

Comment: The part above the error message about CMP0074 fixes that.

Comment: @drescherjm using **cmake_policy** results in: ''cmake_policy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,'

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad: [cmake_policy](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html) is a **CMake command**, not a shell one. Actually, you may ignore the policy *warning*: `This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.`.

Comment: As for the error, [cmake/Utils.cmake:105](https://github.com/D-X-Y/caffe-faster-rcnn/blob/dev/cmake/Utils.cmake#L105) seems to be correct. It is [cmake/Modules/FindLMDB.cmake:15](https://github.com/D-X-Y/caffe-faster-rcnn/blob/dev/cmake/Modules/FindLMDB.cmake#L15) which looks wrong: it uses `PATHS "$ENV{LMDB_DIR}/include"` option for `find_path`, thus dereference the environment variable **without** transforming *native* path (Windows separator, '\') to *CMake* one ('/' as separator). If you set `LMDB_DIR` variable, try to change path separator in it to '/'.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I changed the '\' to '/' in **HDF5_ROOT** but the warning is still there.

Comment: Once again: **Forget** about the *warning*: it doesn't prevent you to build the project and CMake clearly states that it is not *your* problem. If you don't want to see the warning, just pass `-Wno-dev` option for `cmake`. What prevents you from building the project, is the **error**. And the error is NOT related with `HDF5_ROOT` variable.